# Concat 2 sql queries

Tags: php, sql

Hello guys i am trying to combine two sql queries and every time the loop retun an empty array
this is my code

first query

```
    $ONP = ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM EcronRapp where code = '$opt' and date >= CAST('$dd'  AS DATE) and date <= CAST('$df'  AS DATE)")->fetchAllAssociative());
```

second query

```
    $analyse =  ($conn->query("SELECT * from DoublonB where   date >= CAST('$dd'  AS DATE) and dat <= CAST('$df'  AS DATE)")->fetchAllAssociative());
```

and this is the loop

```
    foreach ($ONP as $key => $item) {
    
    $counter = 0;
    $An=null;
    foreach ($analyse as $doublon)
    if ($item["Code"] === $doublon["Ref"]) {
    $An = $doublon["code"];
     $An =  $doublon["code"] . 'times in the file ref  ' . $doublon["Ref"];
    $counter++;
                    }
    $ONP[$key]["Ref"] =  $An;
            }
```

this is my front page

```
    {% for t in response3 %}
    
    {{t['date'] | format('d-m-y')}}
    {{t['mt']}}
    {{t['Code Autorisation']}}
    {{t['Ref']}}
    
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please provide the tables structure and sample data.  Looks you need use single query with join two tables

Comment: well the first one is a table the second one is a view

Comment: Please learn about [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1422451) which should be central in current PHP tutorials, books, and courses. New beginners should not be concatenating values to SQL statements in 2022!

Comment: Which array returns empty? You appear to be assigning to a fetched array, `$ONP`.

Comment: yes it's $ONP .